# Append new line to Java StringBuilder with Outlook Email

Tags: java

I'm using a StringBuilder that is going to be passed to a email service that I created so that the StringBuilder is set as the body of the email being sent. This is what I have now:

```
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("Hello World! " );
buffer.append(something.getMessage());
buffer.append (" \n ");
buffer.append("Welcome to " );
buffer.append(something.getAnother());
buffer.append (" \n ");

emailObject.setBody(buffer.toString());
emailService.sendEmail(emailObject);
```

I would like the message to be displayed in multiple lines, but for some reason even with \n the message still turns out to be in one single continuous line. Does anyone have any idea why this is not working?

Comment: are you sending html email? if so, you'd want <br/> instead of \n

Comment: line separator on windows is \r\n.

Comment: \r\n worked, thanks you!!

Comment: The line separator on Windows is irrelevant -- it is the email standard [RFC 822](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/) (which pre-dates Windows by a few years) which is important. That standard indicates that `CRLF` is the line terminator for email.

Comment: Also, @user974047, why include that extra whitespace surrounding the line terminator? You can use `buffer.append(something.getMessage()).append("\r\n"); // not (" \r\n ")`

Comment: @MrLore - as I mentioned, the line separator in email is *specified* to be `CRLF` and you should **not** use the `System.lineSeparator()` in this case; you should *always* use `"\r\n"` because that's what the RFC specifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML Builder, appendBR() appends new lines

```
HTMLBuilder html = new HTMLBuilder();
html.append(makeHTMLDescription());   
html.appendBR();
```

Comment: HTMLBuilder opens up more than just breakline. worth taking a look at it